# How do I keep a copy of the options I use to run an image in Docker?

Tags: docker, swagger-ui

I just figured out how to get swagger-ui up and running with Docker with my own openapi.json file using the following command:

```
docker run -p 80:8080 -e SWAGGER_JSON=/foo/openapi.json -v ~/source:/foo swaggerapi/swagger-ui
```

The `openapi.json` file is in source control and this could be run in lots of places.

Is there any way to make this command easy to rerun other than just putting it in a README? Can I use a Dockerfile for this? Or could I use docker-compose? The most important part is just to make it easy, and then later to make it easy to change/add options.

I also know I could use a bash script that I could just change, but I'm wondering if there's any Docker way to do it, and not a hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docker-compose is your perfect solution:

```
//docker-compose.yml

version: '3.7'
services:
  swagger:
    image: swaggerapi/swagger-ui
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    environment:
      - SWAGGER_JSON=/foo/openapi.json
    volumes:
      - "~/source:/foo "
```

to run it, just hit `docker-compose up` and you are all set

Comment: Can I use relative paths for my volumes? Like could I mount the current directory just using `.`?

Comment: yeah sure you can go like `".:/foo"`

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using docker-compose for more complicated runs to keep all options in yaml file. Then all you need to start container is `docker-compose up`.
For more options inside application you can use .env file.

I think it’s the clearest way to make containers running and doesn’t require any knowledge for the next users/developers of this environment .